# Haskell check what operator was used

Tags: haskell

Hello I need to make function that will do something based on entered operator.

Is there way to check what operator was used? for example (>=) or (+)

something like

```
check op | op == (+) = "Entered + operator"
         | op == (==) = "Entered == operator"
         | otherwise = "Something else"
```

so

```
 check (+)
```

will return: Entered + operator

Comment: Also related: [How to compare two functions for equivalence?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17045941/791604)

Comment: Short answer: no, there is not.