# Pattern Matching for a new data

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I created a new type with some functions

```
data Gate = MakeGate (Bool -> Bool -> Bool)
andGate = MakeGate (&&)
orGate = MakeGate (||)
```

Now I want to add this type to a new instance of Eq with pattern matching, but I actually get alot of error messages. What I tried so far is

```
instace Eq Gate where
    MakeGate True == MakeGate True = True
```

The Error Message is: "Couldn't match expected type 'Bool -> Bool -> Bool' with actual type 'Bool'"
I was thinking that Bool -> Bool -> Bool means something similar to the (&&) or (||) functions. But it doesn't work that way.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to find out if the two *functions* that the `MakeGate` data constructors wrap always produce the same result of the same input.

We can only find this out by performing an exhaustive search: for both functions calculate the result for all possible inputs, and each time comparing the output. We thus could write it like:

```
type GateFunc = Bool -> Bool -> Bool

eqGate :: GateFunc -> GateFunc -> Bool
eqGate f g = f False False == g False False
          && f False True == g False True
          && f True False == g True False
          && f True True == g True True
```

and then write it as:

```
instance Eq Gate where
    MakeGate f == MakeGate g = eqGate f g
```

The above is however not very elegant: we can do better by generating lists:

```
eqGate :: GateFunc -> GateFunc -> Bool
eqGate f g = (f <$> ft <*> ft) == (g <$> ft <*> ft)
    where ft = [False, True]
```

Or even less code:

```
import Data.Function(on)

eqGate = on (==) ((<*> ft) . (<$> ft))
    where ft = [False, True]
```

Note that for functions with a small (at least finite!) input space, and an output type that is an instance of `Eq`, this can be done, but in general one can not compare two functions. Furthermore even if the two functions have a finite input space, it can go wrong (since the functions could get stuck into an infinite loop). Determining whether two functions are equal is an *undecidable* problem.

Comment: seems pretty good. But is it possibly to put the eqGate function into the instace function?

Comment: Yes, by using a `where` clause.

Comment: I mean not defining a new function. Just putting the methode of the eqGate function into the instance function instead of defining it seperatly?

Comment: Well you can inline it as well. By writing `(MakeGate f) == (MakeGate g) = on (==) ((<*> ft) . (<$> ft)) f g where ft = [False, True]`.

Comment: Thanks! How can I test it?

Comment: In addition to a finite input space the functions also need to have an output type with an Eq instance.

Answer (score 3):

You can't really pattern match functions in Haskell.

MakeGate is a constructor that has the type: (Bool -> Bool -> Bool) -> Gate
But you're giving it a Bool (True). MakeGate True doesn't typecheck.

Maybe you meant `MakeGate f == MakeGate g = f == g` or something like that?

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but function equivalence isn't trivial and pattern matching is for constructors, not functions.

I think what you really want is
    data Gate = AndGate | OrGate | ...

Comment: I try to define the operator "==" by using all the outputs from the possibly inputs

Answer (score 1):

`MakeGate` does not wrap a Boolean value; it wraps a *function*. I'm not sure how you would define an `Eq` instance for `Gate`, because you can't compare functions for equality. The *syntax*, though, would be

```
instance Eq Gate where
    (MakeGate f) == (MakeGate g) = ???
```

The `???` would be the actual equality test, but like I said, it's not clear what you would put here, because you can't use, for instance, `f == g`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define a meaningful `Eq` instance on your `Gate` type, since it contains a function, and [functions cannot be compared for equality](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17046172/465378).

More to the point, though, your question seems confused about a variety of different things about Haskell specifically and higher-order functional programming in general. Consider finding a course, book, or other resource to help you learn in a structured, principled way. (Asking for such resources is off-topic on Stack Overflow, so I will refrain from making specific suggestions here.)