# Compare functions in haskell

Tags: function, haskell

I have a list of commands (`[Command]`) which looks like `[forward 15, left 20, right 10]`. 
I want to add `forward 15` to `[Command]` whenever I see a `forward 15` command. I used `elem` and `==` to compare whether the element is `forward 15` or not but it gives me `No instance for (Eq Command) arising` error.
Also, in another function, I want to add `[left 15, forward 15, forward 15, right 15, right 15, forward 15, forward 15, left 15]` to `[Command]` whenever I see 4 consecutive `forward 15` commands.
Thus my question is how to compare functions, because `forward` is a function and I can't compare it using `elem` or `==`.

`Command` is defined as a `type`, not as a `data`, hence I can't use `deriving Eq`.

```
type Command = Funcs -> (Picture, Funcs)

data Funcs = Funcs {pen :: Bool, angle :: Float, point :: Point, penColor :: Color} deriving (Eq, Show)

forward :: Float -> Command
forward x = ....
```

Comment: Can you show the type definition of `Command` please?

Comment: Thanks I see the type definition. `Command` is a function. My next question is where does `forward 15` come from?

Comment: See also [How to compare two functions for equivalence?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17045941/791604). In short: come up with a plan that doesn't require comparing two `Command`s for equality, cause it ain't gonna happen sanely.

Comment: I'm thinking the most natural approach to what you want to do is to make command a data type.

Comment: I have edited again

Comment: Ah, now it makes sense. See Daniel's answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend making a new data type for commands, and an interpreter into the `Command` semantic domain. For example:

```
data ReifiedCommand
    = Forward Float
    | Backward Float
    | Left Float
    | Right Float
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show)

interpret :: ReifiedCommand -> Command
interpret (Forward x) = forward x
interpret (Backward x) = backward x
interpret (Left x) = left x
interpret (Right x) = right x
```

Now you may compare `ReifiedCommand`s for equality and do whatever inspection you need to do to build a suitable `[ReifiedCommand]`, and then all at once at the end you may `interpret` these into a `[Command]` (or, more likely I think, even a single `Command`).

Comment: I added `DForward Float` to `Reified Command` and `interpret (DForward x) = forward (2*x)` to `interpret`. Then I used `replace [Forward] [DForward] x`. But it gave me error `No instance for (Eq (Float -> ReifiedCommand))
        arising from a use of ‘replace’
`

Comment: That sounds like a new question - none of those elements were presented in the above.  Daniel just gave you a solution which is basically "Don't compare functions, compare the inputs" and you just went right back to trying to compare functions. EDIT: stated another waay, you can't compare `DForward` but you can compare the fully-applied form such as `DForward 2`.

Comment: @BhushanOza Don't do that. Instead, replace `Forward foo` with `Forward (foo*2)`. (You may not be able to reuse the exact `replace` function you have.)

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing a `deriving` clause in your `data` definition.

```
Prelude> data Command = Forward Int | Left Int | Right Int deriving (Eq, Show)
Prelude> Forward 15 == Forward 15
True
```

If you do not have the deriving clause you will see

> No instance for (Eq Command) arising from a use of ‘==’

By the way, while it is true that `Forward` happens to be a (constructor) function, you want to make sure you are doing `==` comparisons not on functions themselves (you can't do this in Haskell) but rather on the result of applying the function. So you can never compare

```
Forward == Forward
```

because the type of `Forward` is `Int->Command` (a function) but you *can* compare

```
Forward 15 == Forward 15
```

as long as you associate the type `Command` with the `Eq` typeclass.

Comment: I just saw your question edit, sorry. Can you show the type definition, please?

Comment: Thanks, deferring to Daniel Wagner's answer.