# Trying to create a Function that checks whether 2 Functions are Equal Haskell

Tags: haskell

```
checkEquality :: (Enum a, Eq b) => (a->b) -> (a->b) -> Bool

checkEquality f g = if f == g then True else False
```

I am trying to create a Function that will check if two Functions are equal but I can't seem to figure what exactly to do when typing the Function. I would appreciate if I can get some pointers as to what to do. What I have tried so far is up there

by equality it means the functions produce the same answer like X^2 = x * x

Comment: How do you define equality of functions?

Comment: they get the same answer

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045941/how-to-compare-two-functions-for-equivalence-as-in-%CE%BBx-2x-%CE%BBx-xx

Answer (score 0):

While the answers so far are correct in that it's not possible to do in general, it is **almost possible** to do in your case. It seems to me like you were given this as a task, so I'll only give you some hints/pointers:

- it's not possible to do in general, for two arbitrary functions of type `a -> b` - so it must mean that you're supposed to use something additional that you've been provided
- in mathematics, for two functions to be, it is often considered enough for them to be equal "on all points", i.e. for all **input values** x, f(x) == g(x)
- in your case, you can indeed check that the results are equal - you have an `Eq b`, allowing you to compare the results of two functions of type `a -> b`
- the only thing you need to figure out is - do you have something else, which would allow you to check all values of type `a`?

The answer is no, but only because I don't think it's possible to do without an additional constraint on what `a` should be (what other instances it should have) - you can already "go through" values of type `a` by using `Enum`, but you don't really know "where to start".